# Attempting to confirm if a user is okay with deleting their account utilizing a random string, but the string they enter is never correct

Tags: python, django

I am utilizing Django to create a website. I am currently making a settings page that should easily allow users to delete their account if they enter a string equivalent to a random string that is set in the context sent to the HTML page. However, the string the user enters is never equal to the random string, despite them being the same. My code is below:

views.py

```
@login_required
def settings(request):
  confirmation = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=7))

  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NewDeleteForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      if form.cleaned_data["confirmation"] == confirmation:
        User.objects.filter(username = request.user.get_username()).update(is_active = False)
        return redirect("home")
      else:
        return redirect("settings")
  
  else:
    form = NewDeleteForm()

  context = {
    'home_act': 'active',
    'contact_act': '',
    'released_act': '',
    'about_act': '',
    'current_act': '',
    'form': form,
    'confirmation': confirmation,
  }

  return render(request, 'turtles/settings.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class NewDeleteForm(forms.Form):
  confirmation = forms.CharField(label = 'Type the letters above to confirm account deletion.')
```

settings.html

```
{% extends 'turtles/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block head %}
<title>Settings</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <h3 style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold;">Settings</h3>
    {{ data }}
    {% if user.is_superuser %}
    <h4>Administrator Settings</h4>
    <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Click here to go to the administrator settings page.</a>
    {% endif %}
    <h4>Delete Account</h4>
    {{ confirmation }}
    <form action="/settings/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id=submit>
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I have attempted to delete whitespace from the strings by utilizing the strip() method, but nothing changed.

Comment: First things first: use a print command to show what the strings actually contain to see if they are what you expect (and surround the strings with quotation marks to show leading/trailing whitespace, also print the strings' lengths to check for hidden special characters). If the program is reporting that the strings aren't matching, the reasonable assumption is that the program is correct.

Comment: I did try to print them, and both strings contained the same things. I have not tried to print their lengths though, will try this. I have tried to strip the whitespace but their could be other hidden special characters that I may have missed, although I'm not entirely sure how they may have appeared.

Comment: when you GET the settings view `confirmation` is generated as a random string to be displayed in the template, then when you POST the form to the settings view `confirmation` is generated as a random string to check against what was entered in the Form by the user, since you are generating `confirmation` twice I would suspect they would never be the same

Comment: Ah this is definitely the issue, thank you!